# Retrieve text within an attribute using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For starts I have this HTML with example data within it:

```
<div class="card {toggle:'someinformation'}">               
    <div class="off"></div>                 
    <div class="on {toggle:'getThisInfo'}"></div>
</div>
```

I want to use jQuery and retrieve this information. Upon asking someone they told me to use the follow (which did not work):

```
    var $card = $(this);
    var this_card = $card.children(".on").metadata()["toggle"];
```

and was told the value of "this_card" would be 'getThisInfo' -- which it did not work. And yes, I did make sure metadata was included in HTML and jQuery as well.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a `metadata()` method. Are you using this plugin: https://github.com/jquery-orphans/jquery-metadata

Comment: That looks like a templating language, maybe you should include all the information in your question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the HTML5 [`data-*`](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) attribute:

```
<div class="card" data-toggle="someinformation">               
    <div class="off"></div>                 
    <div class="on" data-toggle="getThisInfo"></div>
</div>
```

Then access it using jQuery's [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function, like this:

```
var $card = $(this),
    this_card = $card.children(".on").data("toggle"); // "getThisInfo"
```

**Update:**

Based on the extra code posted this should work perfectly for you:

```
var $on_cards = $(".card > .on:visible");
if ($on_cards.length == 2) {
    var $card = $('.card:first'), // was $(this), replaced just for this demo
        this_card = $card.children(".on").data("toggle"),
        $matched_cards = $on_cards.filter('[data-toggle="' + this_card + '"]'),
        event_name = "no_match";
    if ($matched_cards.length === 2) {
        event_name = "found_match";
    }
}
```

This uses jQuery's [Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to find `.on` elements with the same `data-toggle` value.

**Important:** if you need to change the `.on`'s value then *don't* use jQuery's `.data()` function to do so, use:

```
$(selector).attr('data-toggle','your-new-value');
```

This is because `.attr()` and `.prop()` update the attributes in the HTML (which the `[data-toggle=""]` selector checks) whereas `.data()` updates an internal jQuery object without affecting the actual element.

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/c4fQ3/1/ (try changing the `.on` element's `data-toggle` value)

Comment: And for extra JSON fun: "When the data attribute is an object (starts with '{') or array (starts with '[') then jQuery.parseJSON is used to parse the string; it must follow valid JSON syntax including quoted property names. If the value isn't parseable as a JavaScript value, it is left as a string."

Comment: Thank you so much Joe, but say this is for a matching game and I wanted to check how many times the data occurs between the two cards would I simply do "this_card.length == 2" ?

Comment: @Arbitrary - no problem. Are there two instances of `.card` or would you just be comparing the data of `.off` and `.on`?

Comment: There would be two instances of ".card"

Comment: @Arbitrary - I've just added a solution for you. I've checked it in the fiddle and it should solve your problem!

Comment: Hi Joe! Thanks so much for the help you've provided thus far. For some reason the code wasn't working so I decided to test the output for "this_card" -- and it turned out to be "null" or "undefined." Any idea why this may be?

Comment: @Arbitrary - hmm, it looks to be working in the fiddle - is it for you? Would you be able to post how your code looks now? You can use http://pastebin.com or throw it all in a new fiddle if you want.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Bhzv3Q2n -- Here you go, HTML is same as provided but changed to `data-toggle` now.

Comment: @Arbitrary - I think I've seen your problem, what event handler is calling the `checkCards()` function? Could you please post that code? I think it's because you're trying to use `this` but it's not referring to the target element.

Comment: @Arbitrary - no problem :) I think I've figured it out. Here's a slightly modified version of your functions: http://pastebin.com/djeYJ8zy (my changes in capitalised comments) - I didn't have to change much. Basically, `this` in the `toggleCard()` function refers to the element whose event handler called it whereas `this` in the `checkCards()` doesn't. To fix this I just passed `$card` from the first function to the second. This should work perfectly but if it doesn't just post any errors here and I'll take a look!